# Regex URI portion: Remove hyphens

Tags: regex, uri

I have to split URIs on the second portion:

```
/directory/this-part/blah
```

The issue I'm facing is that I have 2 URIs which logically need to be one

```
/directory/house-&-home/blah
/directory/house-%26-home/blah
```

This comes back as:

```
house-&-home and house-%26-home
```

So logically I need a regex to retrieve the second portion but **also** remove everything between the hyphens.

I have this, so far:

```
 /[^(/;\?)]*/([^(/;\?)]*).*
```

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Comment: Pls include a sample of desired output (by second port you mean the second component in the path?)

Comment: It is a custom piece of software. The regex above spits out `house-&-home`. I'm guessing Java but I really have no idea. :(

Comment: @guido Please read the original post. I wish to retrieve the `house-&-home` portion

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=directory\/)(.+?)(?=\/)`

Does this solve your issue? This returns:

`house-&-home` and `house-%26-home`

Here is a **[demo](http://regex101.com/r/wT9qK8/2)**

If you want to get the result:

`house--home`

then you should use a replace method. Because I am not sure what language you are using, I will give my example in java:

```
String regex = (?<=directory\/)(.+?)(?=\/);
String str = "/directory/house-&-home/blah"

Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll("\&", "");
```

This replace method allows you to replace a certain pattern ( The `&` symbol ) with nothing `""`

Comment: Almost.... `/directory/home-&-garden/this` gives **home--garden**..... `/directory/home-blah-garden/this` gives **home-blah-garden**....... `/directory/home-%26-garden/this` gives **home-%26-garden**

Comment: @JoeSmith So the only one that is different is the `home-&-garden`? You want the **&** removed?

Comment: I need all of these examples listed as the same thing. ie **home-garden** or **homegarden** or home--garden** whichever is easiest :)

Comment: Yeah, you would use the regex that I have provide above, then use a replace method. There is no regex that can grab two specific instances, then change and modify it. That is done by the `.replace()` method.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks. Damn. I have no access to scripting. I only get given a regex box. Hmmmm. Thanks for your help nonetheless :)